# User Input to Select and Fill In value for Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have this excel table: A2 to A11 are class names Class_1, Class_2,..., Class_10.
B1 to K1 are student name 1,2,3,...,10

For each student in his class, I will need to fill out his grade

I would like to have a VBA inputbox or userform, so I will just need to answer the question from the inputbox or userform to fill out the grade.

I would imagine the inputbox or userform like this:
Class: Class_1 'equivalent to the row of the cell which in this case row 2
Student: 1 'equivalent to the column of the cell which in this case column B 
Grade: A 'equivalent to the value of the cell which in this case "A"

So if I fill out Class_1,1,A then the VBA will select the cell B2 and will fill in value "A" for that cell.

Comment: Can you provide an example data set? I suspect I know what you're looking to do, and there is a very easy way to do it (without even using VBA), but I want to confirm the way that the data will look before I tailor the solution to fit.

Comment: The data set look similar to this http://imgur.com/UADlMnV

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic bare bones VBA setup for this request. I would assume you'd probably want to tweak it some to make it a bit more. It just loops through each Class/Student combination in your sheet and pops up an input box asking for the grade.

```
Sub getGrades()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change this to your grade sheet

    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intColumn As Integer
    Dim intClassCount As Integer
    Dim intStudentCount As Integer
    Dim strResponse As String

    'get the last row in which a class is present and the last column in which a student is present
    intClassCount = ws.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    intStudentCount = ws.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column

    'run through all of the class/student combinations
    For intRow = 2 To intClassCount
        For intColumn = 2 To intStudentCount

            'Get the response
            strResponse = InputBox("Please enter grade for" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Class: " & ws.Cells(intRow, 1) & vbCrLf & "Student: " & ws.Cells(1, intColumn), "Enter Grade")

            'May want to do some checking here to make sure strResponse is A,B,C,D, or F or whatever...
            ws.Cells(intRow, intColumn).Value = strResponse

        Next intColumn
    Next intRow

End Sub
```

Adding a non-VBA method that is probably a better way to solve this. As I think about the question deeper, and imagine myself having to enter grades for scores of students spread across many classes each I would:

1. Create a new sheet tab that lists each student in one column and their respective classes in a second column. This list would be <#OfStudents> x <#OfClasses> long. You could create this quickly by copy and pasting, or editting the VBA above to just stick the class/student combination into their own rows in the new sheet.
2. In a third column on the new sheet (column C) you could input their grade. Having it in this format a new sheet would allow you to sort and Ctrl+F(find) and Autofilter to only target the students you care about.
3. Back in the original sheet in Cell A3, you could use the following formula to bring through the students grade from the new sheet (I'll call the new sheet "NewSheet") in the formula:

`=INDIRECT("NewSheet!C" & SUMPRODUCT((B$1=NewSheet!$A$1:$A$2000)*($A2=NewSheet!$B$1:$B$2000)*ROW(NewSheet!$A$1:$A$2000)))`

The crazy sumproduct formula will return the row on which the Student/Class combination is found in NewSheet, and the Indirect will fetch the Grade from that particular row.

Going this route you have a few advantages. First, there is no VBA. Not that VBA is a bad thing, it's just not as widely understood as a sheet formula. Second, you get a very usable UserForm/Interface for entering grades with NewSheet and AutoFiltering and Sorting and all the other excel niceties. Third, you can scale this down to a million Student/Class combination without monkeying around with code. Just copy and paste the formula to your ever expanding matrix of Classes and Students and your good to go.

Comment: A couple problems coming up: 1. I cannot stop the inputbox, it keep popping up. 2. This VBA moving line to line. I would like to have the option to choose the location of my input. So I dont have to click enter multiple time to move to my targeted student. Overall, what an awesome code you wrote there. Thank you very much

Comment: I just edited the answer to add a solution that doesn't require VBA. If you stick with the VBA route, then you'll probably want to create a UserForm with a dropdown of classes and students, pulled from the sheet. Once the student/class combo is selected then a grade could be inputted and OK'd... but that's a lot of code/debugging/pain for an interface that is best built a new worksheet tab.